# How do I map a method over an array?

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have a method (which is actually a helper):

```
def f(x)  
  x + 1  
end
```

What I want to do is to map it over an enumerable like so:

```
(1..10).map &f
```

It's obviously doesn't work raising `ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)`
 error. I know that I can call this method in block like so:

```
(1..10).map {|x| f x }
```

But it doesn't look like an elegant solution to me. What else can be done about it?

Comment: When you use `(1..10).map(&:f)`, keep in mind it is actually calling `1.f`, `2.f` and so on. So, unless `f` is a method for `Fixnum`, nothing you try will work

Comment: @CharlesCaldwell this is the reason why I didn't add ":" in the example, to show that `f` is a method defined outside of the `Fixnum`class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use:

```
(1..10).map(&method(:f))
```

Comment: awesome! Had no idea. Could you explain?

Comment: Explain? `Object#method` returns a `Method` object, which can be called like a `Proc`. Anything you pass to `Method#call` will be used as arguments for the method call.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't see any inelegance in this

```
(1..10).map {|x| f x }
```

Normally, you should be using it. But, under special circumstances, a special form is available (you need to call a method on an object and that method doesn't accept arguments).

```
class Fixnum
  def f
    self + 1
  end
end

(1..10).map(&:f)
```

Between these two approaches, I'd take the first one any day.

Comment: Thanks, I thought about adding a class method, but since it's one of the helper methods I think it is better to keep it under its own module without spoiling another classes.